# Simultaneous "lower than" and "higher than" in Perl?

Tags: perl

Is there a way to say

```
perl -e "@array=(1..10); foreach (@array){print qq{$_\n} if ($_>3 and $_<6);}"
```

more simply like

```
perl -e "@array=(1..10); foreach (@array){print qq{$_\n} if (3<$_<6);}"
```

(notice the differences inside the `if` statement).

Edit: running Perl v5.16.3

Comment: Strangely, the answer of @ysth in that post contradicts the fact that my second example return "syntax error at -e line 1, near "$_<""

Comment: That answer is applicable only to perl6. Btw, [`smart match`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) is experimental.

Comment: @mpapec Ahh, I didn't now that. Shouldn't perlop reflect that  - or have I just missed where it says that?

Comment: editing my question to refer my version of perl.

Comment: @Disco3 check http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator

Comment: @mpapec Thanks - I thought you meant the range operator

Comment: `3<$_<6` => `3<$_ && $_<6` four more chars. `;)`

Comment: mpapec: yeah, I know I'm just being *picky* by avoiding that "and" there, but I just wanted to know if there was a way to do the simultaneous comparison :P

Comment: I don't know if it's simpler, but you could do `for my $a (1..10) { print qq{ $a\n } if grep { $a==$_ } (3..6) }` (or `grep {/$a/} (3..6)` if you really want to live on the edge).

Comment: @ialarmedalien besides intention obfuscation, `map, grep, foreach` are performance killers.

Comment: @mpapec performance is a big concern when you're running a one-liner that assesses an array of ten elements. Just demonstrating that TMTOWTDI.

Comment: @ialarmedalien of course not, but consider that `3` and `6` might also be real/fp numbers.

Comment: If you want to save some typing, try the `-l` option, which handles newlines, so `print qq{$_\n}` becomes `print`.

Comment: `perl -E "@r=1..10; $_>3 && $_<6 && say for @r"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. Consider you are looking for a ternary operator, which is quite rare in most programming languages. Usually unary and binary operators will suffice for most needs.

The only example I can think of a ternary operator is the **conditional operator** (cond ? true_statement : false_statement), used as a short-hand for the if-else clause for short statements.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a terneray, Perl6 simply has other precedence rules for '<' where `a < b < c` isn't `(a<b)<c` (why should it ever?) but `a<b && b < c`. But you'll have to wait till Christmas to get that.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. I'm afraid that 'Christmas' can easily be replaced with 'next week/month'.